# Filespec syntax for Perforce to NOT include subfolders

Tags: perforce

I need to run some p4 commands using a filespec with a changelist but I don't want to include files in subfolders.  Typically the syntax is:

```
//depot/projectA/...@1234
```

However, this includes all subfolders.  How can I restict the results to be only for the current folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//depot/projectA/*@1234
```

More details at [Perforce Wildcards](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.092/manuals/p4guide/03_using.html#1068338).